# Set Acceptable Region for My Skewness Test in R

Tags: r

I am writing the below function to let me conduct a `test of skewness` for a vector of samples `(10, 20, 50, 100)` with a `1000` replicate.

```
library(moments)
out <- t(sapply(c(10, 20, 50, 100), function(x)
  table(replicate(1000, skewness(rgamma(n = x, shape = 3, rate = 0.5))) > 2)))
row.names(out) <- c(10, 20, 50, 100)
out
```

**My conditions**

My condition of rejecting the Null hypothesis is that the statistic must fulfil two (2) conditions:

1. less than -2
2. or greater than +2.

**What I have**

But in my `R` function I can only describe the second condition.

**What I want**

How do I include both the first and the second condition in my function?

Comment: I have updated it in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps adding the `abs` would be the easiest approach to meet both conditions

```
out <- t(sapply(c(10, 20, 50, 100), function(x)
  table(abs(unlist(replicate(1000, skewness(rgamma(n = x, shape = 3, rate = 0.5))))) > 2)))
row.names(out) <- c(10, 20, 50, 100)
out
```

Comment: I mean if my statistic is <2 and >2

Comment: @DanielJames yes, when you take the `abs` the `<` becomes `>`

Comment: @DanielJames you can check `v1 <- c(-3, -1, 1, 3);v1 > 2 | v1 < -2#
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE` and `abs(v1) > 2#
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE`

Comment: @DanielJames when you say both conditions should be fulfilled, it would be an OR condition instead of `AND` because an element cannot be both -2 and 2 at the same time

Comment: You are correct, I have changed the `and` to `or` in my question, thank you.