# Do to Normal and Beta exactly what is done to Gamma function

Tags: r

I got a sweet answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68049511/set-acceptable-region-for-my-skewness-test-in-r/68049582?noredirect=1#comment120275576_68049582) for conducting a `skewness` test on simulated data from gamma distribution:

```
out <- t(sapply(c(10, 20, 50, 100), function(x)
  table(abs(unlist(replicate(1000, skewness(rgamma(n = x, shape = 3, rate = 0.5))))) > 2)))
row.names(out) <- c(10, 20, 50, 100)
out
```

This function let me test for skewness with `1000` replicates and sample sizes of `10, 20, 50, 100` all in a function.

I have a result in a table form like below

| . | FALSE | TRUE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 986 | 14 |
| 20 | 972 | 28 |
| 50 | 969 | 31 |
| 100 | 975 | 25 |

I want to do the same to simulated data that follows a Normal distribution. I tried the following by simply replacing the function that simulates Gamma with that of Normal:

```
out <- t(sapply(c(10, 20, 50, 100), function(x)
  table(abs(unlist(replicate(1000, skewness(rnorm(x))))) > 2)))
row.names(out) <- c(10, 20, 50, 100)
out
```

The results do not reject all 4000 runs which cannot be true.

I tried it on the Beta function also as follows:

```
out <- t(sapply(c(10, 20, 50, 100), function(x)
  table(abs(unlist(replicate(1000, skewness(rbeta(n = x, shape1 = 2, shap2 = 8))))) > 2)))
row.names(out) <- c(10, 20, 50, 100)
out
```

The result is the same as the Normal distribution.

**What I want**

How can I make it work for both Normal and Beta as it does for the Gamma distribution?

Comment: If I increase the replicate, i get 10 for the first case i.e. `sapply(c(10, 20, 50, 100), function(x) sum(abs(replicate(10000, skewness(rnorm(x))))> 2) )
[1] 10  6  0  0`

Comment: For the second case, it is diferent `out <- t(sapply(c(10, 20, 50, 100), function(x)
  table(factor(abs(unlist(replicate(1000, skewness(rbeta(n = x, shape1 = 2, shape2 = 8))))) > 2, levels = c(TRUE, FALSE)))));row.names(out) <- c(10, 20, 50, 100);out# TRUE FALSE
10     4   996
20     7   993
50     2   998
100    0  1000`